# Node JS web application to LAN application( Desktop App)

Tags: node.js, electron, desktop-application, node-webkit

I am very new to Node JS. recently developed a web application in NodeJS & hosted it on a common server along with Database for a clinical management.

Now I have an immediate requirement of making it as a desktop application so that users in a clinic can run the exe on their desktop and the application where its installed will create a database for other users to connect and make their updates.

Checked articles with Electron, node-webkit but didn't work for my current solution.

Is there any other alternative solution where I can make it as a desktop for Windows and Mac. Seeking your kind help !!!

Answer (score 0):

There is the software NEXE which shows promising results however, when it comes down too it, Node.JS is a perfectly fine platform for production environments and is quite performant for the use-case you suggest. You can bundle a Node.JS installation and call upon it from your C code using system, exec or spawn calls. You can also open your favourite browser from the command line, while Google Chrome has the --kiosk flag to show in widescreen by default.

Just some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. need to clarify from your end whether my application which has many modules(Mongo DB, UI for showing various reports) will support entire conversion of my application using NEXE.

Comment: Negative, already had a few difficulties in it's use but it is coming along. Also, it's name suggests that it would work better on Windows than Linux however the site says otherwise. But it is most certainly worth a try :) Try on windows as I've had errors, since my comment, on Linux.

Comment: These is also, Porting, the art of re-writing code to match the exact functionality of the system you build? It is much quicker than the initial development of a high-performance system